How to use media queries in Svelte?
I'm using svelte-kit and I'm quite new to it. On my +page.svelte file, I got:
<script lang="ts">
    const { data } = $props();
</script>

where I'm using data to display a hero image.
<div
    class="h-screen w-full bg-cover bg-no-repeat hero-section"
    style={`background: 
            linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00) 22.16%), 
            linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00) 38.11%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50) 99.84%), 
            url(${data.meta.HeroImage.Source}) lightgray 50% / cover no-repeat;
    `}
></div>

and I want to have different placement of gradient for the mobile screens, let say:
<style>
    @media (max-width: 640px) {
        .hero-section {
            background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 76.81%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 99.83%),
                linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 48.56%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 100%),
                url('');
        }
    }
</style>

but as inline background-image overwrites the styles, I could not find a way to make it work. So, question would be, how is it possible in Svelte to use media queries for different screens with dynamic image URL?

the issue is the inline styles, then remove the inline styles and define everything using proper CSS

You can pass the background image url to CSS using a CSS variable:
<div
  class="hero-section h-screen w-full bg-cover bg-no-repeat"
  style:--background-image-url="url({data.meta.HeroImage.Source})"
></div>

<style>
  .hero-section {
    background:
      linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 22.16%),
      linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 38.11%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 99.84%),
      var(--background-image-url) lightgray 50% / cover no-repeat;
  }
  @media (max-width: 640px) {
    .hero-section {
      background-image:
        linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 76.81%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 99.83%),
        linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 48.56%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 100%),
        var(--background-image-url) lightgray 50% / cover no-repeat;
    }
  }
</style>


Oh, right! I completely forgot of using --background-image-url. I applied MediaQuery, but i guess this answer is cleaner. Thank you.
